# function parameters in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, arguments

I can use parenthesis to make cons operator have more priority than function application in this patter match equation:

```
tail (_:xs) = xs
```

However it will be "parse error in pattern" if I try to write this:

```
f (g x) = 7
```

I see that `g x` produces a value and we should directly pass that value. Or in this way `f g x = g x + 7` we make a call to `g` with an argument `x` in the body of `f` definition.

But what is the reason for not allowing to pass a function call in the pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pattern match is about destructuring things. Think along the lines of "I have build this data using constructor `A`". With pattern matching we could see what values we supplied `A`.

This means that means that constructors have to be invertible, we need to be able to figure out a constructors inputs given the results. Now  if you wanted to do the same thing with a function call you'd be in trouble since you can't just invert a function, imagine `f = const 0`.

What it sounds like you want instead is a view pattern. This is where you are passed data, feed it into a function, and then pattern match on the result.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
foo (bar -> Just a) = a
```

This should be read as "Feed the argument to `bar`, then pattern match on the resulting `Maybe`".

Comment: thanks, I found your explanation in the book "Real World Haskell"

Comment: Note that a good alternative to `ViewPatterns` can be `PatternGuards`, in this case `foo x | Just a <- bar x = a`.

Answer (score 2):

We don't pass anything in a pattern. We describe how data that is passed must look like for the corresponding equation to take effect.

Now, it turns out that every value is of the form `g x` for some combination of `g` and `x`, so the pattern `g x` can be abbreviated to just `x`.

Comment: ?? `g` can be any function, so the pattern cannot be abbreviated to just x in this correct version `f g x = g x + 7`

Comment: I think the OP had a specific `g` in mind, he wanted an abbreviation for applying a function to a parameter in the body. Of course `g = id` makes this trivial :)